# Считываются ли деньги с пользователя при отправке sms через приложение?

Tags: android

После заполнения формы заказа, пользователь должен отправить заказ, нажав на кнопку отправки. После этого через приложение должно отправиться sms.

Вопрос: снимут ли с пользователя деньги за отправку `sms` через `SmsManager` ?

Comment: Идем от обратного, почему оператор предоставляющий услуги абоненту на платной основе, вдруг должен пересылать те же смс на бесплатной основе через ваше расчудесное приложение?

Answer (score 3):

ДА!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Я написал себе такую прогу,  теперь звоню с нее, отправляю смс и качаю с инета бесплатно!!!!11!! Теперь хочу еще сделать аналогичную чтобы пи@$дить свет и воду

Comment: За$бись идея!!!